# How to find index of list's max?

Tags: python

There is a list:

```
a= [5,6,8,4]
```

I tried to find index by typing something like this `a.index(max(a))`,but it didn't work.

Instead of printing '3' it printed '0'.

Why did it do that, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It should be printing '2' which is correct.

Comment: `a.index(max(a))` [works for me](https://ideone.com/d6quNx). Can you show an entire program that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: O sorry, not 3, but 2

Comment: Yes, and indexes are 0-based, so the index of `8` in that list is `2`, not `3`.

Comment: O, I understood where problem is. There are not numbers in list, but strings.

Comment: I forgot about len

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine:

```
>>> a = [5, 6, 8, 4]
>>> a.index(max(a))
2
```

If you want to avoid going through your list multiple times you may want to use something like:

```
>>> a = [5, 6, 8, 4]
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=lambda a: a[1])[0]
2
```

It also works if those integers are actually strings:

```
>>> a = ['5', '6', '8', '4']
>>> a.index(max(a))
2
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=lambda a: a[1])[0]
2
```

Also, as pointed out by [RoadRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238915/roadrunner) in the comments, you can also use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> a = [5, 6, 8, 4]
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
2
>>> a = ['5', '6', '8', '4']
>>> max(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
2
```

Comment: You can also do `max(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]`.